# Find index of special character in string by its offset using perl

Tags: perl

I've a string which has special character "|" [pipe]. Here, I want to know the pipe index value on it offset value.

Trying with below code.

```
my $string = "json|xsp|xml|dml|xspt";
my $lc_i = index( $string, "|", 2);
print " lobcol index of string : $string is : $lc_i \n";
```

output:

```
lobcol index of string : json|xsp|xml|dml|xspt is : 4
```

But, I'm expecting the `$lc_i` value as : 8.

Is the above approach is correct ? 
Let me know, where I went wrong. Please help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "I'm expecting the $lc_i value as : 8." ***WHY?!***

Comment: Position of the second pipe in the string; just a wild guess..

Comment: The '2' in `index( $string, "|", 2);` means start from character 2, not get the second match.

Comment: You must need the index of these characters for a second step, for instance to then use `substr` to extract the words between the pipe `|` characters? If you explain what that next step is then we will be able to help you much better; I suspect that your purpose is much better served by using regular expressions

Comment: @xxfelixxx: It actually means to start from *offset* 2, at character 3

Comment: @Boradin/xxfelixxx : Thanks for the info. Then, how can I know the index of  second occurrence of character "|".

Comment: @Boradin/xxfelixxx : http://www.perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/index_function.html #  check Example 3a. It's working

Answer (score 2):

I think the tidiest way to do this is with a global regular expression

This program scans the string for all pipe `|` characters and pushes the offset of each one onto the array `@indices`. After that is done, you can access the location of, say, the second pipe by `$indices[1]` which is 8

I have added a working solution using [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html). As [**choroba** has explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32094053/622310), the last parameter, *POSITION*, to `index` is a *character offset* into the string where it should start looking. So if `index` finds your first pipe at offset 4, you want to call it the second time with a *POSITION* of 5, otherwise it will just find the same pipe again

I hope you'll agree with me that the regex solution is cleaner and more concise

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $string = "json|xsp|xml|dml|xspt";

{
    my @indices;
    push @indices, $-[0] while $string =~ /\|/g;
    say "@indices";
}

{
    my @indices;
    my $offset = 0;
    while () {
        my $index = index($string, '|', $offset);
        last if $index < 0;
        push @indices, $index;
        $offset = $index + 1;
    }

    say "@indices";
}
```

#### output

```
4 8 12 16
4 8 12 16
```

Answer (score 1):

The third argument to [index](http://p3rl.org/index) is the position in the string, not the number of occurrence. You have to create your own subroutine:

```
sub nth_index {
    my ($string, $substr, $count) = @_;
    my $pos = 0;
    for (1 .. $count) {
        $pos = 1 + index $string, $substr, $pos;
        return -1 if $pos == 0;
    }
    return $pos - 1
}

my $string = '|json|xsp|xml|dml|xspt|';
for my $i (0 .. 8) {
    my $lc_i = nth_index($string, '|', $i);
    print "lobcol $i-th index of string : $string is : $lc_i.\n";
}
```